# How Pop to root view using TabView in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Here's an example of the expected behavior i want. :

[image]this my code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            DetailView(path: $path, number: 0)
                .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { index in
                    DetailView(path: $path, number: index)
                }
        }
        Button("Go To Root") {
            path = NavigationPath()
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    var number: Int
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink("Go to Random Number", value: Int.random(in: 1...1000))
        }
        .navigationTitle("Number: \(number)")
    }
}

#Preview {
    DetailView(path: .constant(NavigationPath()), number: 1)
}
```

i want if i tap 2 times on tabItem its back to root again.
in that code im using normal button. i want change using tabItem

Comment: This may help: https://notificare.com/blog/2022/11/25/a-better-tabview-in-swiftui/

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `ContentView` body with `TabView`. Then handle `onTapGesture(count: 2)`

```swift
enum Tab {
    case list
    case detail
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection: Tab = .detail
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            DetailView(path: $path, number: 0)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Detail", systemImage: "star")
                }
                .tag(Tab.detail)

            //Config other tabItem if needed
            //...
        }
        .onTapGesture(count: 2) {
            guard selection == .detail else { return }
            path = NavigationPath()
        }
    }
}
```

Now `DetailView` is a root view of `Tab = .list`. So if you want to push to another view, do it on `navigationDestionation` here

```swift
struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    var number: Int
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Button {
                    path.append(1)
                } label: {
                    Text("Go to Random Number")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Number: \(number)")
            .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { num in 
                //Put random number's view here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure that if you add another tabitem, it should have its own NavigationStack and path.

Comment: I think it depends on his/her purpose. There is nothing wrong with a view without `NavigationStack`. It's like a one-page view. @koen